# Head First C# method issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this weird issue occuring everytime I run my game "Day at the Races" in Visual Studio. So basically I'm working with Forms. I have 4 PictureBoxes, with dog photos. Dogs info are stored in an array. After each race I want to put these Pictures back on the starting line. So I have made a method:

```
public void SetToStartingPosition()
{
    for (int j=0; j < GreyhoundArray.Length; j++)
    {
        GreyhoundArray[j].MyPictureBox.Left = 0;
    }
}
```

I run this method every time the race is finished and here's what happens:
All 4 PictureBoxes goes back to starting position (x=0) as intended, then the MessageBox pops up, and when I press "OK" to close it, a random number from 1 to 3 of PictureBoxes(Dogs)   goes back to the right position(x=600)... I just have no idea why closing this MessageBox has such weird influence, I don't see any connection between these two, also no other methods have anything to do with PictureBox.Left. Any ideas of what's happening would be very appreciated.

```
public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    for (int i = 0; i <GreyhoundArray.Length; i++)
    {
        GreyhoundArray[i].Run(); //method making PictureBoxes move to the right

        if (GreyhoundArray[i].Run() == true) //GreyhoundArray[i].Run() is true when the race is finished
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            **SetToStartingPosition();**
            winDog = i;
            MessageBox.Show("Dog number " + (winDog + 1) + " has won!");
            groupBox1.Enabled = true;
            button1.Text = "RESTART!";

            for (int k =0; k < GuysArray.Length; k++)
            {
                if (GuysArray[k].MyBet != null)
                {
                    GuysArray[k].Collect(winDog);
                    GuysArray[k].ClearBet();
                    GuysArray[k].UpdateLabels();
                }
            }
             break;
        }

    }

}
```

Edit: 
Oh wow, you just gave ma a clue whats wrong, so there actually was PictureBox location changing line in Run() method, which I was sure would stop when one of the dogs win the race, but I didnt break the loop, so it was still going, and setting dogs back on their position. All I had to do was adding 'break;' in the end of the loop. And just for your and some others info:

```
  ` public bool Run() 
    {
        if (MyPictureBox.Left > 600 - MyPictureBox.Width)
        {
            return true;

        }
        else
        {
            Location += MyRandom.Next(1, 4); 
            MyPictureBox.Left = StartingPosition + Location;
            return false;
        } `
```

Thanks for help tho, thats a bad and ambarrasing start of my Stack Overflow "carrer" :(

Comment: This sounds like a concurrency problem.  In essence there are multiple threads changing the dog's position at once, resulting in unexpected behavior.

Comment: It might be useful to see the code for the `Run()` method

Comment: Without seeing the Run() method, it appears your code is wrong. You're callng `GreyhoundArray[].Run` twice (once by itself, and once in the first `if` statement). It looks like you should either remove the `GreyhoundArray[i].Run();` that's on a line by itself, or store the result of that call in a boolean variable and use that variable in the `if` statement instead of the second call to `Run()`. But this is easy to figure out yourself - learn to use the debugger, and step through the code to see exactly how the code is executing and when the image moves when it shouldn't.

Comment: I agree with @KenWhite that calling `Run()` twice does look incorrect, but it doesn't explain the behavior you're seeing. (at least without seeing the run function)

Comment: Consider [edit]ing your title to make it a bit clearer what your question is. "Head First C# method issue" doesn't tell me anything.

Comment: @SamIam Yeah you were right, about that Run() method, I have already changed it, and edited my post. Thanks :)

Comment: @KenWhite Yeah, you guys were right about Run() method, thanks :)

Comment: You are moving the dogs one at a time. When one dog wins, you show the message and stop the timer. But the following dogs will still execute in the loop. You'll need either a `break;` or a `return;` once you've decided a dog has won, so the others are no longer updated. So, you reset the dogs back to the starting position, then all dogs `> i` will then move again

Comment: @Rob exactly that was the problem, I have added `break;` in the end of the loop

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging